# Tor unmet dependency libssl1.a

Tags: dependencies, tor

I have followed steps at [Tor Project guide for Ubuntu](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu)
and am running into a problem with `libssl1.1` unmet dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tor : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
   Recommends: tor-geoipdb but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: torsocks but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I tried installing `libssl1.1` and that did not work either.

Tried the bundle - The TOR browser set up is on my panel but not responsive.
So the bundle didn't open up to config.

Later I tried installing it again with `sudo apt -f` that didn't work.
Then I went back to (http://linuxbabe.com/) and AGAIN tried installing it via PPA. The first time it didn't work but this time it did.

*So If the Tor Project's 'Tor on Ubuntu or Debian' doesn't work try the bundle. If the bundle doesn't config then try installing it by PPA.

Comment: try `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: if no errors then try installing again

Comment: You have to file a bug with the TOR project as they are maintaining the repository you are using.

Comment: Personally I suggest the tor bundle https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

Comment: Recommended tor-geoipdb & torsocks.  Installed torsocks.  Tried  tor-geoipdb -- following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tor-geoipdb : Depends: tor (>= 0.2.9.11-1~d89.stretch+1) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Explane filing a bug with Tor?